# Matching two tables using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have these two tables
One table is called LineMax

```
  OrigNode  DestNode           DivisionNum  Prefix  FromMP  ToMP    Suffix
 7764   25961                     3          AB       18    20.9    
7764    50213                     3             AB    18    17.3    
7765    35444   3   AB  0   1.5 
7841    35444   3   AB  6   1.5 
15390   25961   3   AB  23.75   20.9    
25961   7764    3   AB  20.9    18  
25961   15390   3   AB  20.9    23.75
```

And I have another data set

```
    OPER_MNT_DIV_CD TRK_CLS_NBR LN_PFX  SEG_BGN_MP  SEG_END_MP  LN_SFX
       4                   1                362.7       362.71     
       4                    1                362.71    362.83      
       4    1                               362.83    362.98       
         4  1                               362.98    363.35       
     4  1       363.35  363.4      
      4 1       363.4   363.54     
     4  1       363.54  363.67     
    4   1       363.67  363.81     
    4   1       363.81  363.95     
    4   1       363.95  364.1      
     4  1       364.1   364.15     
     4  1       364.15  364.5      
     4  1       364.5   364.55
```

I am trying to match my data. Basically I want to match to my second table it should have the same Prefix,Suffix, and Divison Number.

So basically

Prefix=LN_pfx

Suffix=LN_SFX

DIVISIONNUM=OPER_MNT_DIV_CD

I also want my first to Mp and from Mp to be contained within the SEG BGN MP AND SEG END MP like this $Seg_BGN_MP<=fromMp<ToMp<=Seg_end_mp4$

But I cannot seem to get my code to work. My second data table had some white space so I removed them and I turned Oper MNT DIV CID from a string to an int to make an easier comparison.

I also removed all the white space and turned every string capital in my first table.
But I cannot seem to get the matches I want.

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import math
x=pyodbc.connect("DSN=DBP1")
table1=pd.read_csv("LineMaxOrder.csv")
s2="select oper_mnt_div_cd, trk_cls_nbr, ln_pfx, seg_bgn_mp, seg_end_mp, ln_sfx, crvtr_mn, crvtr_deg, xstg_elev from dcmctrk.crv_seg where trk_cls_nbr = 1 order by oper_mnt_div_cd, ln_pfx,ln_sfx"
table1=table1.drop(table1.columns[[0]],axis=1)
dChange=pd.read_sql_query(s2,x)
dChange["LN_PX"]=dChange["LN_PFX"].str.strip()
dChange["LN_PFX"]=dChange["LN_PFX"].str.upper()
dChange["LN_SFX"]=dChange["LN_SFX"].str.strip()
dChange["LN_SFX"]=dChange["LN_SFX"].str.upper()
dChange["OPER_MNT_DIV_CD"]=dChange["OPER_MNT_DIV_CD"].astype(int)
dfObj2=table1.select_dtypes(["object"])
table1[dfObj2.columns] = dfObj2.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
table1[dfObj2.columns]=dfObj2.apply(lambda x:x.str.upper())
table1=table1.fillna('')
w=[]
for idx,row in table1.iterrows():
    a=row[3]
    b=row[4]
    c=row[7]
    agu1=row[5]
    agu2=row[6]
    big=max(agu1,agu2)
    small=min(agu2,agu1)
    result=dChange[(dChange["OPER_MNT_DIV_CD"]==a)&(dChange["LN_PFX"]==b)&(dChange["LN_SFX"]==c)]
    if result.empty:
        continue
    else:
        result[(result["SEG_BGN_MP"]<=small)&(result["SEG_END_MP"]>=big)]
        if result.empty:
            continue
        else:
            print(result)
            w.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the pandas merge to combine joins as : inner, left, or right and link by matching fields